# Spring mvc json using nested polo 406

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I am using spring mvc @ResponseBody to try to return a json, Spring mvc 4.1.2 and I got these libraries imported in Maven:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

The method in controller is:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getuser", produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Model getUser(Model model) {
    List<User> users=new ArrayList<User>();

    User u = new User();

    u.setId("123");
    u.setPasswd("dvas");

    model.addAttribute("status", 0);
    model.addAttribute("user", u);

    return model;
}
```

The User code is simple:

```
public class User {

private String id;
private String passwd;
}
```

But I keep getting 406 in testing, and if I change the return type to User, then it is fine, I can get the json.

And can I return a nested pojo as json using spring mvc?

Comment: What URL is giving you the HTTP 406 error?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/myprojectname/getuser

Comment: 1) Don't use the Spring `Model` class with controller methods that should return JSON, just return the data to convert to JSON.  2) It should be possible to return any arbitrary POJO from the controller method and have it serialized to JSON.  3) I couldn't reproduce the 406 error for the URL `getuser`: does using `getuser.json` instead help?

Comment: You are right, I used the pojo and it worked. The main reason it didn't work out the first time was that I forgot to add setter and getter in the pojo. Thanks very much!